# How to use matplotlib with ArcGIS 10.1 without Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Error?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, python-2.7, matplotlib, visual-c++

I have problems using the matplotlib for python with ArcGIS 10.1

If I run the code below as a script tool in ArcMap. No pdf is generated and when I close ArcMap this error is shown.

[image]

If I run the code from IDLE a similar error is shown for C:\Python\ArcGIS10.1\pythonw.exe but the pdf is generated correct.

If I run the code in a cmd prompt no error code is shown and the pdf is generated correct.

Does anybody know how to make the script work as a script tool in ArcMap?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

fig = pyplot.figure(figsize=(8.27,11.69))

axis1 = fig.add_subplot(311)
axis1.plot(range(10))

fig.savefig('multipleplots.pdf')
```

Comment: Are you running pyplot in interactive mode (does the plot show up automatically when you create the figure)? Interactive mode is incompatible with both ArcGIS and IDLE.

Comment: No the plot does not show up automatically. I also tried adding matplotlib.pyplot.ioff() to the code but the error still pops up. But maybe there is another way I need to turn off interactive mode?

Comment: That should have done it...does it work with a different format, like png?

Comment: No change output to .png does not create any output within ArcMap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm super late to the party, but I had the same problem today and your post came up during my google search. So I guess posting a solution could be useful to someone in the future.

Anyways, I avoided the Microsoft Visual C++ crash when closing ArcMap by closing the `matplotlib` figure after saving it.

```
pyplot.close(fig)
```